# Piecewise Linear approximation of Brownian Motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, numerical-methods, brownian-motion

I'm looking to show that if you have a partition $0 = t_0 < \cdots < t_n = T$, then for any $t \in [0,T]$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} W^{(n)}(t) \to W(t)$ where $W(t)$ is standard Brownian motion. $W^{(n)}(t)$ is a piecewise continuous linear approximation such that
$$
W^{(n)}(t) = W(\mathrm{t}_i) + \left(W(\mathrm{t}_{i+1})-W(\mathrm{t}_i)\right) \frac{t-\mathrm{t}_i}{\mathrm{t}_{i+1}-\mathrm{t}_i}, \quad t \in \left[\mathrm{t}_i, \mathrm{t}_{i+1}\right)
$$

I'm struggling a bit here, if $t$ is taken on each $t_i$, the boundary of the partition, then everything cancels; however, for the $t \in (t_i, t_{i+1})$, I don't know how to proceed here.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The main result you need is called the functional central limit theorem or Donsker's theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donsker%27s_theorem

Comment: @Ian : If you look carefully at the way the problem is expressed in this posting, I think you'll see that this is not Donsker's theorem at all. Notice that it was ASSUMED that the process you start with is the standard Brownian motion. That is not to be proved; it's given at the outset. And this proposition seems not to be about probability at all; it's only about piecewise linear approximations converging pointwise to a function. The only thing you need to know about the function $t\mapsto W(t)$ in this problem is that it is continuous.

Comment: @MichaelHardy That's true; it's a sufficiently straightforward case that I assumed the real interest was in the more interesting question (the one that lets you actually do numerics, where the slopes are just given as independent $N(0,1)$ variables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $W:[0,+\infty)\to\mathbb R$ is continuous.

Continuous functions on compact sets are uniformly continuous. The domain of this function is not compact, but consider $[0,a]$ when $a>0.$

For $a>0$ and $\varepsilon>0,$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that for every $s_1,s_2\in[0,a],$ if $|s_1-s_2|<\delta$ then $|W(s_1)-W(s_2)|<\varepsilon.$

(The reason for bounding this interval $[0,a]$ at a finite number $a$ rather than at $+\infty$ is that a value of $\delta$ that is small enough on such a bounded interval may not be small enough on the whole line. Do values of $\delta$ that are small enough go down to $0$ as $a$ grows? I.e. with Brownian motion does that happen? At this moment I don't know and my mind is on other things than answering that.)

But the statement above that begins with "For $a>0$ and..." is also true of $W^{(n)},$ the piecewise linear approximation. So let $\delta$ be small enough for $W$ and also small enough for $W^{(n)}.$ Then make $n$ big enough so that $\mathrm{t}_{i+1}-\mathrm{t}_i<\delta.$ Then $W^{(n)}(t)$ and $W(t)$ both differ from the values of $W$ at either of the two endpoints by less than $\varepsilon;$ hence from each other by less than $2\varepsilon.$ That should do it.